# ExecutorService not running tasks in parallel

Tags: java, rest, jvm, quarkus

In short, when running code [1], I get the output [2]. When I uncomment the `latch.await();` at the last line, I get the output [3].
It seems that `ExecutorService` does not run the tasks in parallel when I am blocking the main thread. When I am not waiting in the main thread, parallel execution is as expected.
Anyone know how to avoid this?

PS: This is running in Quarkus framework, on a `@RequestScoped` context resource.

[1]

```
    private void setProfileData(String clientId, List<ProfileData> profileDataList)
      throws InterruptedException {
    final int chunkSize = 500;
    var chunks = IntStream.range(0, (profileDataList.size() + chunkSize - 1) / chunkSize)
        .mapToObj(i -> profileDataList.subList(i * chunkSize,
            Math.min(chunkSize * (i + 1), profileDataList.size()))).collect(Collectors.toList());

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(chunks.size());

    for (var c : chunks) {
      executor.submit(() -> {
        try {
          log.error("Start write");
          //simulate work on the chunk
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          log.error("End write");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          latch.countDown();
        }
      });
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    //latch.await();  // wait for all tasks to complete
  }
```

[2]

```
2023-06-21 17:30:25,838 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-147-thread-1) Start write
2023-06-21 17:30:25,845 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-148-thread-1) Start write
2023-06-21 17:30:25,851 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-149-thread-1) Start write
...
2023-06-21 17:30:30,843 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-147-thread-1) End write
2023-06-21 17:30:30,849 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-148-thread-1) End write
2023-06-21 17:30:30,856 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-149-thread-1) End write
```

[3]

```
2023-06-21 17:32:22,571 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-177-thread-1) Start write
2023-06-21 17:32:27,576 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-177-thread-1) End write
2023-06-21 17:32:27,592 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-178-thread-1) Start write
2023-06-21 17:32:32,598 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-178-thread-1) End write
2023-06-21 17:32:32,615 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-179-thread-1) Start write
2023-06-21 17:32:37,620 ERROR [com.fan.fun.ser.MigrationService] (pool-179-thread-1) End write
```

Comment: Are you sure this all comes from same loop? I'd expect the pool threads to be called `pool-XXX-thread-YYY` where YYY varies, same XXX if they are all from same thread pool.

Comment: Yes, It is the same loop

Comment: You're showing output from different thread pools - the  thread names should not all end "-1"

Comment: Could it be that you are calling `setProfileData` several times in a loop? That would explain the pool numbers, as well as the different outputs.

Comment: It seems that you both are correct. There is an external for loop, which is looping the function. About the real problem - that at [3] there is a serial execution - it was that I was giving only 500 items in the profileDataList. Thank you for your answers. That really helped me.